# Routing traffic to specific network through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I need your help regarding a network configuration between different machines.

I have 6 Ubuntu servers which have two NICs, eth0 + eth1. eth0 has a public IP which connects to the internet through the provider gateway. eth1 is connected to a switch along with the rest of the servers and the interfaces are bridged together to form veths. With the current configuration the veths on each server communicate directly. After having a need to add two more servers, it was impossible for the hosting company to add them to the switch along with the others. So they made the **same** configuration with the NICs but this time the eth1 interfaces were connected with a crossover cable.

My question: Is it possible to route traffic from the secondary interfaces using either the public IP of eth0 on all machines, or using a VPN connection? I tried connecting one of the first six with one from the new servers using VPN and I had successful connectivity.

What I tried so far:

- Route traffic to the veth network using the tunnel interface

  ```
  route add -net <veth_network> netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev tun0
  ```

without luck

Is there an alternative?

Comment: I think better you ask this question on https://serverfault.com

Comment: I'm a little confused about your current setup. You want to have connectivity between the two clusters? You'll need to get routing involved if they aren't in the same layer 2 broadcast domain. Do you want an always-on VPN that connects the two clusters through eth 0 for regular file transfer or load balancing or what? I'm just having trouble picturing what exactly you're trying to do. Maybe a diagram would help?